# JQuery Table Sort issue - Skipping column disables first mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables, tablesort

I have created a basic table in js fiddle. I am using the datatable sorter function, however if you click along the headers, or click a header, skip one and click another, it seems to ignore the first mouse-click. (To replicate the issue click on Confirmation Period, then ABN, then back to Confirmation Period)

Any thoughts?

```
<table id="tableSort" class="tableSort" cellspacing="0" style="margin-top:20px;margin-left:10px;">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Confirmation Period</th>
        <th>Legal/Entity Name</th>
        <th>ABN</th>
        <th>Business/Trading Name</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>34</td>
    <td>78</td>
    <td>b</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>90</td>
    <td>g</td>
</tr>
```

and the JS...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tableSort').dataTable({
        "searching": false,
            "paging": false,
            "info": false
});
```

});

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wcdg3ddL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table is actually sorting as expected. There are two reasons why it looks like the columns aren't sorting:

1. You have insufficient rows in your table to assess whether or not sorting is working. Add few more rows of data and you should see what I mean.
2. Because you've removed the arrows from the header row with your custom styling you cannot accurately gauge how the sorting is behaving. If you add in the default CSS styling you can see the direction in which a column is being sorted.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/indoctrinate/wcdg3ddL/1/) where I have added sufficient rows so that the columns appear to be sorting correctly.

I just added more rows to your fiddle:

```
<tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>34</td>
        <td>78</td>
        <td>b</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: thanks for your response. Im not sure if you looked at the JSFiddle example?<br/> 1. The arrows are not hindering the sorting. Sorting is working fine. <br/> 2. There are 2 rows of data to show that the sorting is working.<br/>To replicate the issue click on Confirmation Period, then ABN, then back to Confirmation Period...

Comment: See update. I have updated your fiddle to show you what I mean. Did you add extra rows of data like I suggested?

Comment: The main issue is that you only have two rows of data which is insufficient to assess whether or not sorting is working. I suggested adding the CSS styling back in so that you could see the arrows to better gauge how the sorting was working.

Comment: @Angavar...Got it! So weird...It is working with two rows, however there is a delay. you are right about adding more rows, i just cant see the logic? Either way thanks!

Comment: @Angavar...More on this - The table looks to be sorting up to 2 columns, so with little (2 rows) data it looks as if its only sorting one, then ignoring a mouse click, when it is actually trying to sort the next in conjunction...

Comment: No worries, please accept the answer. Think of it this way: if you only have 1 row in your table, that table is sorted 100% of the time. You can't sort a table with only 1 row. A table with two rows will be sorted 50% of the time. If the table is already sorted, then clicking a button to make it sort will appear to do nothing.

Comment: got it. Will accept the answer when i get some rep! Thanks